# Matlab use of vCPUs of VM for parallel loop

Tags: matlab, azure, parallel-processing, virtual-machine, vcpu

I have a big nested calculation in MATLAB and changed the programming to parallel processing (PARFOR). My CPU only has 4 cores. So I thought, maybe I could use a Azure VM with 16 cores to provide even more workers and reduce computing time.So the question is, do the vCPUs of the VM count as additional pools or will the code still work with only 4 workers?
thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The max number of local workers on a machine is up to the version and license of your current Matlab.

Plesae see the marked answer of [`Matlabpool Maximum Number of Local Workers on one computer - Parallel Computing`](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25987-matlabpool-maximum-number-of-local-workers-on-one-computer-parallel-computing) from MathWorks forum, as the screenshot figure below.

[image]